# How to handle blatant ripoffs of SO answers

Tags: discussion

I asked a question on SO and, after a while, I found a solution, so I answered my own question - so that, in the future, I could still find it.
Today, I found this link:

```
http://www.simosh.com/article/cebdjdag-does-fast-report-4-delphi-7-support-utf8-using-frxuserdataset.html
```

Which is a byte-by-byte copy of

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139306/does-fast-report-4-delphi-7-support-utf8-using-frxuserdataset
```

Does SO allow such a copy?

Comment: All user content on SO is licenced under Creative-commons. So, generally, yes. That site doesn't seem to be following the attribution guidelines, but it's disputed whether they're enforceable.